# How to execute finally block after os.kill() function in python

Tags: python, operating-system

Main Program

```
import os,pymsgbox
try:
    c=os.getpid()
    with open("sample.txt","w") as fp:
        fp.write(str(c))
    while True:
        print ""
except Exception,e:
    print  e
finally:
    pymsgbox.alert("Done")
```

File which actually kill process

```
import os,signal
with open("sample.txt","r") as fp:
    pid=fp.read()
os.kill(int(pid),signal.SIGTERM)
```

In finally block i want to close all open connections.So how to call finally block

Answer (score 1):

Tried this:

```
import atexit
def final_sub():
    pymsgbox.alert("Done")

atexit.register(final_sub)
```

The atexit module defines a single function to register cleanup functions. More info could be found here: [atexit — Exit handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html)

also.. instead of calling atexit.register, you can do the same via decorator:

```
@atexit.register
def final_sub():
    pymsgbox.alert("Done")
```

But, there was a discussion [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-February/038472.html)
Go through it, and atexit may not work in your case. So you need a handler for the SIGTERM signal.

Try to add this code at the start of your file and "finally" starts to work as you want on SIGTERM. Hadler raises normal SystemExit on SIGTERM, so Finally works:

```
import signal
class SigTerm(SystemExit): pass
def sigterm(sig,frm): raise SigTerm
signal.signal(15,sigterm)
```

So, the full code will be something like this:

```
import os
import pymsgbox

import signal
class SigTerm(SystemExit): pass 
def sigterm(sig,frm): raise SigTerm 
signal.signal(15,sigterm)

def final_sub():
    pymsgbox.alert("Done")

try:
    c=os.getpid()
    with open("sample.txt","w") as fp:
        fp.write(str(c))
    while True:
        print("")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    final_sub()
```

Comment: I have to add above code in Main file or in another file? @Nick

Comment: also.. instead of calling atexit.register,  you can do the same via decorator :)
like:

@atexit.register
def final_sub():

Comment: Thanks but when i run file which kills process at that time Main file stop its process and it does not go in finally block. @Nick

Comment: it runs the function final_sub(), so if finally has the same function call - you will get the same result.

Comment: Actually when program is in process and if user click on stop button it should kill process and close all ope connection. I just want core logic

Comment: "Finally" will be honored only on sys.exit, I think.
On all common exceptions atexit(sys.exitfunc) will work.

Comment: moved our discussion to the main reply

Comment: But final_sub() is executing in both condition if program finish its execution or when it throws error,i want in specific situation only

Comment: what about adding this in the start of your main program:

`import signal
class SigTerm(SystemExit): pass
def sigterm(sig,frm): raise SigTerm
signal.signal(15,sigterm)`

Probably, FInally will work fine without atexit after this. The question if you use Linux/Mac or Windows?

Comment: Check the version without atexit, but with handling SIGTERM signal. Updated the main reply. @AnkitaAgharkar